# Binding Virtual Event to a selection in a Combo Box in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to configure text in a label once a choice is made in the combo box. How would I bind these two events?

Combo Box Script:

```
self.info = StringVar()
    self.infoarea = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable = self.info, state = 'readonly')
    self.infoarea.place(x = 15, y = 530)
    self.infoarea.config(values = ('PM10910', 'PM10909'))
```

Script for the bind:

```
def callback1(PM10910):        
        self.infotext2.config(text ='info')

self.infoarea.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",callback1)

def callback2(PM10909):        
        self.infotext2.config(text ='info')

self.infoarea.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",callback2)
```

I have read something about using ComboboxSelected, but I doubt that I am using it correctly.

With this script, I am able to change the information once in the label once, but when I click the other option in the combo box the label does not change.

Comment: why are you binding to the event inside the function you are binding? Or is that a mistake in the indentation?

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake. I am not really sure how to format the binding. @BryanOakley